# Using an intermediate entity in LINQ to Entities leads to System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

My entity model is made primarily of 6 entities that join among themselves based on 2 attributes.

I have to build 182 LINQ queries based on old plaintext SQL queries. Those queries have some parts in common, so that in order to avoid repeats I have built a little framework to build the queries on top of building blocks. I will show examples right away.

Since all queries are made of a join between a combination of the 6 entities (starting from root entity `SectionA`) I have built, for my convenience, a wrapper class `JoinOfSections` that wraps all those sections.

On that class I can perform simple LINQ evaluations that are common to all 182 queries.

For example

```
    public override IQueryable<QueryRow> Run(Models.auitool2014Entities dataContext, int aUserId, DateTime? dataInizioControllo, DateTime? dataFineControllo, string[] a52Exclude, bool codifiche2014)
        string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

        var sj = dataContext.sezione_a.SelectMany(
            a => dataContext.sezione_d.Where(d => a.A03 == d.A03 && a.utente == d.utente).DefaultIfEmpty(),
            (a, d) => new SezioneJoin { A = a, D = d });

        sj = CommonFiltering(sj, aUserId, dataInizioControllo, dataFineControllo, a52Exclude);

        return (from SezioneJoin ssj in sj
                let a = ssj.A
                let d = ssj.D

                where
                 a.utente == aUserId &&
                 (
                 String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.A21) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.A51) ||
                 a.A51.CompareTo(a.A21) < 0 ||
                 a.A21.CompareTo(now) > 0 ||
                 a.A51.CompareTo(now) > 0 ||
                 a.A21.CompareTo("19000101") < 0 ||
                 a.A51.CompareTo("19000101") < 0
                 )
                select ssj).Select(Select());
    }

    protected virtual IQueryable<SezioneJoin> CommonFiltering(IQueryable<SezioneJoin> sj, int aUserId, DateTime? dataInizioControllo, DateTime? dataFineControllo, string[] a52Exclude)
    {
        sj = sj.Where(x => x.A.utente == aUserId);
        if (dataInizioControllo != null)
        {
            string dataInzio = dataInizioControllo.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            sj = sj.Where(x => x.A.A21.CompareTo(dataInzio) >= 0);
        }
        if (dataFineControllo != null)
        {
            string dataFine = dataFineControllo.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            sj = sj.Where(x => x.A.A21.CompareTo(dataFine) <= 0);
        }
        if (a52Exclude != null)
            sj = sj.Where(x => !a52Exclude.Contains(x.A.A52));

        return sj.Take(Parameters.ROW_LIMIT);
    }
```

`Select()` method is a simplification of a common pattern. Since the result set **must** be flattened in order for older components to process it I have invented another adapter layer

```
[Serializable]
public class QueryRow
{
    public string A01 { get; set; }

    public string A01a { get; set; }

    public string A01b { get; set; }

    public string A02 { get; set; }

    public string A03 { get; set; }

    public string A11 { get; set; }

    public string A12 { get; set; }

    // Dozens of string members
}
```

In order not to copy&paste...

```
    protected virtual Expression<Func<SezioneJoin, QueryRow>> Select()
    {
        return sj => new QueryRow
        {
            A01 = sj.A.A01,
            A01a = sj.A.A01a,
            A01b = sj.A.A01b,
            A02 = sj.A.A02,
            A03 = sj.A.A03,
            A11 = sj.A.A11,
            A12 = sj.A.A12,
            A12a = sj.A.A12a,
            A12b = sj.A.A12b,
            A12c = sj.A.A12c,
            A21 = sj.A.A21,
            A22 = sj.A.A22,
            A23 = sj.A.A23,
            A24 = sj.A.A24,
            A25 = sj.A.A25,
            A31 = sj.A.A31,
            A31a = sj.A.A31a,
            A31b = sj.A.A31b,
            A32 = sj.A.A32,
        }
```

`SezioneJoin` class represents a row in the dataset that is a combination of `JOIN`s between a number of entities, is as follows. It is designed in order for any query to instantiate its custom JOIN (e.g A inner D, A left D left E, A inner D left H)

```
public class SezioneJoin
{

    public SezioneA A { get; set; }

    public SezioneD D { get; set; }

    public SezioneE E { get; set; }

    public SezioneF F { get; set; }

    public SezioneG G { get; set; }

    public SezioneH H { get; set; }

}
```

Basically **all** queries require that the dataset is filtered on the current user ID and optional check dates, plus they **all** allow a maximum number of results.

I paid my attempt to generalize the concept with `NotSupportedException` (exception message translated by me)

> Unable to cast type 'DiagnosticoSite.Data.Query.SezioneJoin' into
>   'DiagnosticoSite.Data.Query.SezioneJoin'. LINQ to Entities supports
>   only Enum or primitive EDM data types

The problem may lie in the `(a, d) => new SezioneJoin { A = a, D = d }` line: if I select an anonymous type the LINQ query works just flawlessly, but then I cannot pass the query object to the protected method that **decorates** it with additional common checks.

Being them 182 queries it is important for me to find a way to add common checks to all queries that **is not** copy&paste.

I would like to know how I can manipulate a LINQ to Entities query using a "buffer" or "intermediate" entity that is not in the data context so that the query itself, being complex, may be passed as a parameter to a decorator method.

The error occurs both on enumerating and on calling `ToString()` method of the IQueryable returned by `Run`. I needed the ToString to extract the query issued to DB

Comment: That code should work. Can you add the definition of `SezioneJoin` ? And also specify which version of Entity Framework you are using.

Comment: Just to be sure, you say that you translated the exception message. Are you sure that the message says that it cannot cast `DiagnosticoSite.Data.Query.SezioneJoin` to `DiagnosticoSite.Data.Query.SezioneJoin` (the same type) ?

Comment: This seems a problem of materializing the entities too late. I haven't read the question in detail but non-model classes with LINQ-To-SQL triggered this alarm immediately. You can't select a non-model object with a LINQ query before calling ToList or otherwise enumerating the SQL results into actual .NET CLR objects because the LINQ engine wouldn't be able to map your code to queries. I am most likely wrong but wanted to add my 2 cents.

Comment: What are the types of `A03` and `utente`? If they are not primitive EDM data types (int, string, etc), then that's probably the source of your problem.

Comment: @AntoineAubry EF is 6.1.3. I have added info about another class but that is not relevant to the error. The concept is that all queries differ by 1) the combination of JOINs and 2) **part** of the WHERE condition

Comment: @Machinarius: First, this is L2Entities, not L2Sql. Second, you can totally select a non-model object with a LINQ query before materialization.

Comment: All members of the Sections classes are native. Strings and int

Comment: Does it help to explicitly set all the properties of `SezioneJoin`?  e.g. `new SezioneJoin { A = a, D = d , E = null, F = null, G = null, H = null}`

Comment: To be more clear: SezioneJoin and QueryRows are classes defined **out** of Entity Framework for my personal convenience

Comment: @StriplingWarrior just tried: did not help at all

Comment: @StriplingWarrior that will have the same problem, because it still asks EF to create a `SezioneJoin` without telling EF what a `SezioneJoin` is. It can't e.g. know that there isn't yet another `XYZ` property of type `DateTime?` that is being left null, Anonymous types on the other hand include every one of their fields by definition, so they can always be mapped (assuming that each property can itself be understood, etc.)

Comment: I've used intermediate DTO types like this in my EF queries quite a bit, without any difficulty. The only reason I can think this would be different is that I typically flatten the data in those cases so I'm not using other entities as my individual properties. What if, instead of `E = null`, etc., you use `E = new SezioneE{}`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF presumably doesn't know what a `SezioneJoin` is.

You could define such a types as an entity, and maybe it would work. However, if your `CommonFiltering` is realistic, that wouldn't be necessary. Consider:

```
var q = CommonFiltering(dataContext.sezione_a, aUserId, dataInizioControllo, dataFineControllo, a52Exclude)
  .Join(
        dataContext.sezione_d,
        a => new { A03 = a.A03, User = a.utente },
        d => new { A03 = d.A03, User = d.utente },
        (a, d) => new SezioneJoin { A = a, D = d }
      )
    .Where(x =>
      ...
    ).Take(Parameters.ROW_LIMIT);

protected virtual IQueryable<AType> CommonFiltering(IQueryable<SezioneA> sj, int aUserId, DateTime? dataInizioControllo, DateTime? dataFineControllo, string[] a52Exclude)
{
  sj = sj.Where(x => x.utente == aUserId);
  if (dataInizioControllo != null)
  {
    string dataInzio = dataInizioControllo.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    sj = sj.Where(x => x.A21.CompareTo(dataInzio) >= 0);
  }
  if (dataFineControllo != null)
  {
    string dataFine = dataFineControllo.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    sj = sj.Where(x => x.A21.CompareTo(dataFine) <= 0);
  }
  if (a52Exclude != null)
    sj = sj.Where(x => !a52Exclude.Contains(x.A52));

  return sj;
}
```

Really, you only need to worry about passing the result of the join rather than the components to it, if a point of the filtering cares about some quality of both `A` and `D` at the same step. Here your filtering cares only about `A` and that's a defined type.

If you really need to deal with something like that though, you could build up the expression.

To simplify let's just consider a version with the signature `IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(IQueryable<T> source, bool makeA21Match)`. If `makeA21Match` is true then we add `Where(sj => sj.A.A21 == sj.D.A21)` to the query, and otherwise we don't:

```
private static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(IQueryable<T> source, bool makeA21Match)
{
  if(makeA21Match)
  {
    var getA = typeof(T).GetProperty("A"); // .A
    var getD = typeof(T).GetProperty("D"); // .D
    var getAA21 = typeof(SezioneA).GetProperty("A21"); // a.A21 for some A.
    var getDA21 = typeof(SezioneD).GetProperty("A21"); // d.A21 for some D.
    var parExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)); // sj.
    var getAExp = Expression.Property(parExp, getA); // sj.A
    var getDExp = Expression.Property(parExp, getD); // sj.D
    var getAA21Exp = Expression.Property(getAExp, getAA21); // sj.A.A21
    var getDA21Exp = Expression.Property(getDExp, getDA21); // sj.D.A21
    var eqExp = Expression.Equal(getAA21Exp, getDA21Exp); // sj.A.A21 == sj.D.A21
    var λExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(eqExp, parExp); // sj => sj.A.A21 == sj.D.A21
    source = source.Where(λExp);
  }
  return source;
}
```

This is a lot more convoluted than just having a lambda expression in the C# code, and lacks compile-time checking of types, but it does mean we can apply the expression to a queryable of anonymous type, and performance should be comparable in such a case.

A balanced approach would be to first filter `sezione_a` and `sezione_d` as much as possible, since that can be done more easily, and then have a method that only deals with the more complicated hand-coding of expression-building for those cases that absolutely need it. You can even cache the `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` produced if necessary.

Comment: Now the question is: could you **actually** use greek letters for variable names in C#? That is a lot of fun if you are creative enough :-)

Comment: Returning to the topic: I don't think that making SezioneJoin an entity is even feasible, because it is a wrapper. It would have no mapped table. Or can I create a complex type (not mapped to table) that wraps EDM entities? That would be the fix

Comment: You can use any letters in C# variable names. I don't recommend it, but this was already breaking the guideline of using English terms with US spelling, so why not? And even if `SezioneJoin` could be created I don't recommend it, since it would be an entity type with no entities, better to go with the rest of the answer; filter as much as you can with explicitly typed filters and use the approach at the end when necessary.